# Confusion in Serre's Local fields book

Tags: group-cohomology, exact-sequence, derived-functors

I read that for right exact functors we consider left derived functors and the resolutions that we consider are projective resolutions...

I read that for left exact functors we consider right derived functors and the resolutions that we consider are injective resolutions...

This i read in M.Scott Osborne's Basic homological algebra book in section 6.2 [http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Homological-Algebra-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/038798934X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038798934X)

But in Serre's Local fields in chapter seven he said that $A^G$ is left exact which means he should consider injective resolutions for right derived functors but he considered Projective resolutions..

He said in section 2 of chapter 7 that :

> By definition, the right derived functors of the functor $A^G$ are cohomology groups of $G$ with coefficients in $A$. Recall briefly how they are computed.
>
> choose a resolution of the $G$- module $\mathbb{Z}$ by **Projective $G$ modules**

I got confused with this approach..

please let me know what i am missing..

Comment: Where does he say that? It would be best if you told us *exactly* what he says (and where, exactly)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : I have edited the question.. please see that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he is doing is the following.

- First, he knows there is an isomorphism $A^G=\hom_G(\mathbb Z,A)$, so the derived functors of $(-)^G$ are the derived functors of $\hom_G(\mathbb Z,-)$, which are exactly $\operatorname{Ext}_G(\mathbb Z,-)$.
- Second, to compute $\operatorname{Ext}_G(\mathbb Z,A)$ he knows he can either use an injective resolution of $A$ and apply to it the functor $\hom_G(\mathbb Z,-)$, **or** take a projective resolution of $\mathbb Z$ and apply to it the functor $\hom_G(-,A)$.

Well: he picks the second option.

Comment: Well, it **is** correct.

Comment: I checked that $A^G=\hom_G(\mathbb Z,A)$ is true.. Could you please say something more about your second statement.... I guess i got it but i am not sure...

Comment: My second statement is a basic result of homological algebra: one says that $\hom$ is a *balanced* functor because one can compute its derived functors with respect to either one of its variables. This is explained and proved in most textbooks on homological algebra. For example, see the book by Hilton and Stammbach, or Weibel's.

Comment: I have checked it and convinced myself.. Thank you :)